# Dropping a stacked column below others using Foundation grid

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

Is there a way to do the following using Foundation's grid?

```
On Large Screens
################ ################
#              # #              #
#              # #    Col 2     #
#              # #              #
#              # #              #
#    Col 1     # ################
#              # #              #
#              # #    Col 3     #
#              # #              #
#              # #              #
################ ################

On Medium Screens
################ ################
#              # #              #
#              # #    Col 2     #
#              # #              #
#              # #              #
#    Col 1     # ################
#              # 
#              # 
#              # 
#              # 
#################################
#                               #
#            Col 3              #
#                               #
#                               #
#################################
```

The code I'm working with.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-6 columns">
    <p>Column 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="large-6 columns">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-12 columns">
        <p>Column 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-12 columns">
        <p>Column 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas on the best way to do this? The content in Col 2 is going to have `text-align: right;` and will not take up much space but the content in Col 3 will be much wider than whats in Col 2 so it will be line-broken which is what the designer was trying to avoid by dropping col-3 below.

Comment: Give col1 and col3 `min-width`s which, when added, extend the width of the small screen.

Comment: @MrLister Can you clarify with an example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible if you can put the cols in a single row container like this..

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-6 small-6 columns">
    <p class="tall">Column 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="large-6 small-6 columns">
    <p>Column 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="large-6 small-12 columns">
    <p>Column 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://codeply.com/go/rZuxJWtm98

Comment: Thanks, this works. Is this a good way to handle it? It seems strange to me to have a row with columns that add up to more than 12.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with more than 12 units..just makes the extra columns wrap